# ORCA Api - C# p/invoke issues

Tags: pinvoke, powerbuilder

I'm trying to work with the Powerbuilder ORCA Api from C#, and I'm having some issues with marshaling. [Here](http://pborca.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pborca11.h) is the C header file for the ORCA Api, I'm trying to implement the PBORCA_SccGetConnectProperties function, which requires the pborca_scc struct.
Here are my definitions:

```
[DllImport(OrcaModule, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int PBORCA_SccGetConnectProperties(IntPtr ORCASession,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Workspace,
    ref OrcaSccInfo SCCInfo);

public delegate int TextOutDelegate(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string data,
        int userData);

public delegate void BuildProjectDelegate(
        OrcaBuildError BuildError,
        IntPtr userData);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public sealed class OrcaSccInfo
{
  internal IntPtr Wnd = IntPtr.Zero;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
  internal string ProviderName = null;

  internal int Capabilities = 0;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
  internal string UserID = null;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 301)]
  internal string Project = null;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 301)]
  internal string LocalProjPath = null;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 301)]
  internal string AuxPath = null;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 301)]
  internal string LogFile = null;

  internal TextOutDelegate SccMsgHandler = null;
  internal BuildProjectDelegate OrcaMsgHandler = null;
  internal int lCommentLen = 0;
  internal int lAppend = 0;
  internal IntPtr CommBlk = IntPtr.Zero;
  internal int DeleteTempFiles = 0;
}
```

When calling the function like so:

```
ret = Interop.PBORCA_SccGetConnectProperties(session.Handle,
                @"D:\PB11-test\test.pbw",
                ref scc);
```

I receive a FatalExecutionEngineError with a message that it could be due to marshaling errors. I've gone over this again and again and can't seem to find where I'm making a mistake with how I'm marshaling the function, the struct, or the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

For the delegate definition, that second parameter should be a uint rather than an int.

```
public delegate int TextOutDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string data, uint userData);
```

The first parameter in the second delegate could possibly be a ref or a pointer.

```
public delegate void BuildProjectDelegate(ref OrcaBuildError BuildError, IntPtr userData);
```

And in the class definition you could try [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] on the delegate members, and in any methods that take delegates.

Is the size of the OrcaSccInfo class coming out the same size in C# as you'd expect it to be in the C++ code? When I put it into Linqpad and get the size I get 2584 for Auto charset, 1320 with Ansi charset and 1316 when I set Pack=1  on 64-bit and 1300 on 32-bit.

Have you tried replacing the strings with StringBuilders, particularly in the Dllimport declaration itself?

And is it possible that your delegates are being disposed of before they're being used?
Passing a delegate to unmanaged code doesn't create a reference that the garbage collector can see so unless you hold on to a reference to the delegate in your own code it'll be disposed of earlier than you expect.

Comment: Hmm, no luck with any of your suggestions, and I did try pinning the callbacks as well as the instance of the OrcaSccInfo class. It looks like when compiling in C++ for 32 bit I get 1300 bytes for the size of the struct, I can't tell for sure how it's compiled in the DLL I'm accessing but it's "supposed" to be unicode. Thoughts?

Comment: Definitely not unicode if it's coming out 1300 in the C++, is your C# giving the same size then? You shouldn't need to pin the delegates, just maintain a reference to them within your code, like in a field on the class.

Comment: Are you using that OrcaSccInfo class anywhere else successfully? And if not have you tried changing all the internal access modifiers to public?